# Recover iOS keychain data on a new phone

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, keychain

I have stored credentials of a specific app in iOS’s keychain using the `expo-secure-store` package and the kSecAccessbility attribute is `when_unlocked_this_device_only`. I have saved a copy of my phone with iCloud backups, but now I have factory reset my phone. How do I recover my old keychain items, does the iCloud backup contain my keychain items and where can I find them?

Comment: Based on the developer forums link you shared, you will need to restore your device from the iCloud backup to recover the keychain items.

Comment: I have restored my device from iCloud backup. I installed the app from Testflight in my old phone, after restoration, I can see the iCloud symbol next to my app, and when I clicked it, it says Unable to Install "<App Name>" - You must purchase this app to install it. Any idea what I should do here?

Comment: Or is there a way to read the values from the keychain without launching the app?